# Elementwise subtraction error: In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices, `X` and `Y`, and I want to perform elementwise subtraction. Here's my code:

```
whos('X', 'Y')
Z = X - Y;
```

The following output shows the sizes of `X` and `Y`, which are identical, but then gives an error message suggesting that they are, in fact, not the same size:

```
Name          Size             Bytes  Class     Attributes

X          1995x10             159600 double              
Y          1995x10             159600 double            

In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be
the same.
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Does `Z` already exist in the workspace? If so, try `clear Z` and try again.

Comment: Type `whos X Y` and paste the result in your question

Comment: `Z` does not already exist; I have tried clearing it anyway, and this makes no difference. Calling `whos` on `X` and `Y` again shows that they are of the same size (see the edit above).

Comment: Something that may be of interest: I have an existing matrix `M`, and then `X = M(U, :)`, where `U` is an array of indices.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that that error is for that line?

Comment: Does the same happens with smaller matrices? For example, do you get the same error if you do `X = rand(100); Y = rand(100); Z = X - Y;`?

Comment: Agreed with Dan; even if those were different sizes you should get "matrix dimensions do not agree".  The error you give has to come from something along the lines of `Z(1)=X-Y;`